# Google Cloud Build does not ignore file when using Github App

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-build

I'm using Google Cloud Build with Kaniko (for docker layer caching).

I wanted to add a first step before running kaniko and realised that my `.gcloudignore` is not taken into account when Github app send the trigger. It works when I call the command myself `gcloud builds submit`.

.gcloudignore

```
# If you would like to upload your .git directory, .gitignore file or
# files from your .gitignore file, remove the corresponding line below:
.git
.gitignore
.gcloudignore
.dockerignore
#!include:.gitignore
#!include:.dockerignore
```

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        docker -v && ls -lah
  - name: 'gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest'
    id: 'image-base'
    args:
      - --build-arg=git_hash=$SHORT_SHA
```

When using the CLI it works well, the ls is showing only what should be there.
But when gcb receive a github trigger the `ls -lah` will print a lot of files that should be ignored with the include:.dockerignore

I don't understand and it drives me insane 
Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defined [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore), `gcloud` cli can update files in different commands. using a `.gcloudignore` file allows `gcloud` cli to not upload these files.

That's all, it's only for `gcloud`, not for other code upload process.

Comment: wow it's so confusing :| 
having different behavior in local and remote is such a pain and it's harly explained by the doc. Thanks a lot !